# Create other textfiles from one file?

Tags: .net, vb.net, .net-4.0

I was hoping someone could offer me a little help please? I have the following coding which changes rows in my textfile, it basically reads a number from a textbox and creates another textfile with the numbers of rows that match the number in the textbox. The coding works fine.

```
Dim lines() As String = IO.File.ReadAllLines("C:\test1.txt")
IO.File.WriteAllLines("C:\test1.txt", lines.Skip(CInt(TextBox1.Text)).toarray)
IO.File.WriteAllLines("C:\test2.txt", lines.Take(CInt(TextBox1.Text)).toarray)
```

Now I was hoping to make some changes, what I would like is to read the number from the textbox and create 5 separate textfiles. So for example if textfile 1 has 60 rows and textbox1 has the number 50 then i will have the following textfiles after running the coding.

```
textfile 1 - 10 rows remaining
textfile 2 - 10 rows
textfile 3 - 10 rows
textfile 4 - 10 rows
textfile 5 - 10 rows
textfile 6 - 10 rows
```

and in the event of textfile1 having only 1 row then i would like the following

```
textfile 1 - 0 rows remaining
textfile 2 - 1 rows
textfile 3 - 0 rows
textfile 4 - 0 rows
textfile 5 - 0 rows
textfile 6 - 0 rows
```

and if the textfile1 was to have 5 then it would be

```
textfile 1 - 0 rows remaining
textfile 2 - 1 rows
textfile 3 - 1 rows
textfile 4 - 1 rows
textfile 5 - 1 rows
textfile 6 - 1 rows
```

if the textfile1 was to have 4 then it would be

```
textfile 1 - 0 rows remaining
textfile 2 - 1 rows
textfile 3 - 1 rows
textfile 4 - 1 rows
textfile 5 - 1 rows
textfile 6 - 0 rows
```

etc
Is this possible? Many thanks

Comment: What meaning has the `textbox1.Text` value of 50? Can the user also specify the number of files to be created? Which line should be in which file or is it arbitrary?

Comment: Hi Tim, the textbox1 value means the rows of data so for example if File1 had 100 rows of data and textbox1 has the number 50 this means the user wants to remove the top 50 rows from File1 and create new files with these rows.  Yes sorry i forgot to mention that there is a textbox2 which is a numeric field and this is the number of textfiles that get created.

Comment: Hi Tim, any help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, i'll give it a try, although your requirement is too localized for SO and it's unlikely that it will ever be helpful for anybody else. Your comment makes the questions answerable.

One approach is using LINQ to group the lines by `Index Mod FileCount`:

```
Dim lineCount = Decimal.ToInt32(NumericUpDown1.Value)
Dim fileCount = Decimal.ToInt32(NumericUpDown2.Value)
Dim file1Lines = IO.File.ReadAllLines("C:\test1.txt")
Dim newFile1Lines = file1Lines.Skip(lineCount)
Dim lineGroups = (
    file1Lines.Take(lineCount).
               Select(Function(l, i) New With {.Line = l, .Index = i}).
               GroupBy(Function(x) x.Index Mod fileCount).
               Select(Function(grp) New With {
                          .FileIndex = grp.Key,
                          .Lines = grp.Select(Function(x) x.Line)
              })) 

IO.File.WriteAllLines("C:\test1.txt", newFile1Lines)
For i = 0 To fileCount - 1
    Dim path = String.Format("C:\test{0}.txt", i + 2)
    Dim lineGroup = lineGroups.FirstOrDefault(Function(lg) lg.FileIndex = i)
    If lineGroup Is Nothing Then
        IO.File.WriteAllLines(path, {""})
    Else
        IO.File.WriteAllLines(path, lineGroup.Lines)
    End If
Next
```

Comment: @JackSparrow: Edited my answer after you've accepted it. Removed the `ToDictionary` to minimize memory consumption.

Answer (score 1):

Even lower memory consumption; only one line is ever stored in RAM at a time:

```
Dim files As Integer = 5
Dim lines As Integer = 50

Using rdr As New IO.StreamReader("C:\test1.txt")

    Dim output(files) As StreamWriter
    For i As Integer = 0 To files
       output(i) = New StreamWriter(String.Format("C:\test{0}.txt",i+1))
    Next i

    Try

        Dim currentStream As Integer = 1
        Dim line As String
        While (line = rdr.ReadLine()) <> Nothing
           If lines > 0 Then
               output(currentStream).WriteLine(line)
               currentStream += 1
               If currentStream > files Then currentStream = 1
               lines -= 1
           Else
               output(0).WriteLine(line)
           End If

        End While

    Finally
        For Each writer As StreamWriter In output
            writer.Close()
        Next writer
    End Try
End Using
```

Comment: Have you tested it? The `Using rdr As New IO.StreamReader("C:\test1.txt")` causes an IOException in the following `For-Loop` at `New StreamWriter(String.Format("C:\test{0}.txt",i+1))`. The `While Loop` will never enter. Apart from that i'm not sure if it answers OP's requirement. The lines should not be equally divided into all files. The first file is an exception.

Comment: I typed it directly into the reply window. I expect the problem here is needing additional arguments in the constructors to allow separate streams to open the file for reading and writing at the same time. Otherwise, I accounted for the first file, because currentStream is never set to 0.